# PhoneGap, same origin policy issue only on Android

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, soap

I have a very simple app, I just need to test some features on iOS and android.
The code is the same.
Here's the very simple code (PhoneGap 3.6.3-0.22.1 skeleton project):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.soap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The relevant JS part is the following one, called after the `deviceready` event is fired:

```
soapTest: function() {
  console.log("going to authenticate!");
  $.soap({
         url: 'http://<my_url>/api/?wsdl',
         method: 'login',
         data: {
         username:'<user_here>',
         apiKey:'<api_key_here>'
         },

         success: function (soapResponse) {
            console.log("Success");
         },
         error: function (SOAPResponse) {
            console.log("Fail");
         }

         });
 }
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions in SO, but what is strange here is that this code works in the iOS simulator ("Success"), but it does not work for Android ("Fail").

Please note that I have the line `<access origin="*" />` in every config.xml file, the general one and the platform-specific ones.

Debugging in the jquery.soap.js library, this is the SOAP response in Android:

```
11-18 05:03:49.410: I/chromium(889): [INFO:CONSOLE(387)] "{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","responseXML":null,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.soap.js (387)
```

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you sure your android device has internet access? (this may be an issue if you're using android emulator and haven't enabled data or wifi)

Comment: thanks for your comment, actually yes, it is connected and on the browser I can visit the url, and of course I have the internet permission in the manifest file

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @MichaelBurger no, sorry